# Неправильно написан парсер в функции main()

Tags: python, парсер, selenium

Вот мой код, у меня неправильно составлен парсер, но как составить я не понимаю.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
user=UserAgent()
profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override',user.random)
driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get('https://rabota.ykt.ru/') 

#Это смена юзер агента
time.sleep(10)

def rabota(navigate):
    soup=BeatifulSoup(table,'lxml')
    vacansii=soup.findAll(class_='class="r-vacancy_list_item ng-scope')
    for vacansia in vacansii:
        knopka=vacansia.find(class_='r-vacancy_title').text
        print(knopka)
def navigate():
    table=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.r-vacancy_list').get_attribute('innerHTML')

def main():
    a=rabota(navigate(table))
    table=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.r-vacancy_list').get_attribute('innerHTML')


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Вот мой парсер вакансий. Примерно так я понимаю написание парсера. Он должен проходить по вакансиям и собирать их названия.Я только начинающий и можете указать ошибки, где я не так составил, я пока плохо понимаю что писать в функции main и какие аргументы ей передавать.

Вот код ошибки

```
(rabota) E:\Python>E:\Python\rabota\parser.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\rabota\parser.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Python\rabota\parser.py", line 27, in main
    a=rabota(navigate(table))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'table' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот код, который будет работать для вашей задачи:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_page(url):
    return requests.get(url).text

def get_works(html):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
    vacansii=soup.findAll(class_='r-vacancy_list_item ng-scope')
    for vacansia in vacansii:
        knopka=vacansia.find(class_='r-vacancy_title').text
        print(knopka)


if __name__=='__main__':
    url = 'https://rabota.ykt.ru/'
    get_works(get_page(url))
```

Answer (score 2):

Если ваш парсер правильно работает, то это должно помочь

```
def navigate():
    table=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.r- ...(не вмещается строка')
    return table

def main():
    a=rabota(navigate())
```

Помните, что переменные локальные переменные функций не видны вне их, что бы сохранить значение лучше возвращать его из функции через `return`

Так же значения внутри скобок это аргументы передающиеся в функцию, ведь она сама так же не может увидеть переменных других функций

Так же для простого веб скрапинга можно обойтись просто модулем `requests`, если вы просто берете `html` страницы и парсите его

Comment: Функцию rabota тоже надо переделать - у неё параметр navigate, а используется внутри table. В общем, какая-то ботва там с navigate и table наверчена по всему коду.